# how to get image name within a base directory(Application Directory) in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In my base directory I have a folder for image. In this folder I have only one image and I want to get image name from it and load it to Image Source. In this code I get an error:

> Could not find file'C:\Users\Santhosh\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\imagetest\imagetest\bin\Debug\ImageFolder\System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String].jpg'

How can I get an image name from base directory?

This is my code

```
string ImageFiles=Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"\\ImageFolder\\",".jpg").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName).ToString();
image1.source== new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\ImageFolder\\"+ImageFiles+".jpg"));
```

Comment: Is youre in the debug folder ?  In this directory : C:\Users\Santhosh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\imagetest\imagetest\bin\Debug\ImageFolder ?

Comment: And don't call .ToString on Select

Comment: yes debug folder

Comment: If i remove .tostring() on select it shows red mark error

Comment: .Select() return System.Linq.Enumerable. You can't do .ToString on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `FirstOrDefault` to get the first file from the directory, or `null` if the directory does not contain a file with a matching name:

```
var imageFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ImageFolder");
var firstFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, "*.jpg")
    .Select(Path.GetFileName)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (firstFile != null)
{
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path.Combine(imageFolder, firstFile)));
}
```

Or shorter, without `GetFileName` and a subsequent `Combine`:

```
var imageFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ImageFolder");
var firstFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, "*.jpg")
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (firstFile != null)
{
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(firstFile));
}
```

Comment: And How to delete this image from directory,I write code for File.Delete but it cannot delete the image shows an error "The process cannot access the file 'Jackalope_Room_Full.jpg' because it is being used by another process." How to Delete it?

Comment: @santhosh It would be probably better to ask about deletion as a separate question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is how youre first line should  look like :

```
string ImageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\ImageFolder\\").Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName).First();
```

Comment: Thanks :) And How to delete this image from directory,I write code for File.Delete but it cannot delete the image shows an error "The process cannot access the file 'Jackalope_Room_Full.jpg' because it is being used by another process." How to Delete it?

Comment: You probably have it open. Just close it before running the program